# política de mesma origem como contornar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cross-platform

Possuo um site em um certo domínio e dentro desse site um Iframe com domínio porta e host diferente, porém dentro desse Iframe eu desejo realizar um `"document.getElementsByClassName('classe')[0].innerText"` de uma classe de fora do Iframe, porém aparece o **erro**:

> "VM2184:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of
>   undefined
>       at :1:131"

Acredito que seja pelo fato de estar tentando ler um dado de fora do Iframe, pesquisei varias formas de solucionar mas até agora não achei uma resposta que me atendesse.

Código:

```js
 $(document).ready(function teste() {
            var dados = window.document.getElementsByClassName('classe')[0].innerText
            if (dados != null) {
                document.getElementById('nome').value = dados;
                $.post("/WebAPI/api/funcao", { data: dados });
                reset();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está tendo um problema de [Política de "mesma origem"](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/Seguranca/politica_de_mesma_origem), ainda.

Para tentar acessar o conteúdo do parent você pode utilizar algo como `parent.document.getElementsByClassName('suaClasse')[0].innerText` e aí sim ter um problema com o CORS pois não é possível realizar comunicação entre um iframe e outro domínio:porta.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, isso acontece por que você está executando o script dentro da sua pagina principal! Então realmente não existe essa classe na sua pagina principal e sim no iframe, para acessar o as classes/id's dentro do iframe você precisa fazer isso:

`document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].ownerDocument.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getElementsByClassName("exemplo")`

Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: Existe um caminho reverso também? tipo eu to no Iframe executando um código para pegar um elemento da página principal?

Comment: Ao contrario não! Seria bem inseguro! Imagina você colocar um script na sua pagina que ferra com a index de quem colocar o iframe nela!

Comment: faz sentido kk, muito obrigado esclareceu bastante as coisas aqui!

Comment: Se consegui responder com precisão, poderia marcar como correta? =D

Answer (score 0):

Para quem está precisando pegar o elemento da página principal e passar para um Iframe de domínio diferente leia a resolução a seguir, após pesquisar milhares de sites chineses e turcos eu finalmente achei uma solução.

Na pagina que você vai enviar o elemento coloque o seguinte código

```js
window.parent.frames[0].postMessage( tes, '*');
```

Na página que vai receber o elemento coloque o seguinte código

```js
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
 //faca qualquer coisa aqui como atribuir a uma variável e tal e usar depois, coloque o alert só para ver se o elemento estava chegando e sim ele chegou!
  alert(e.origin + "-" e.data);
},false);
```

Já deixo avisado que não sei se o método usado é seguro para evitar que outros sites peguem esse elemento que você está transferindo mas, está funcionando.